# Calculating Used Memory of a JVM

Tags: java, memory, jvm, heap-memory

I want to calculate the used memory of a JVM heap. I did the following in a sample application.

1. Set JVM heap size as Xms=200mb and Xmx=200mb.
2. Did the calculation as follows using Java Runtime APIs. It gave me following output for sample program.

   Runtime total memory : 192413696

   Runtime max memory : 192413696

   Runtime free memory : 39734096

   Runtime available memory = (max - total + free) = 39734096

   Percentage of used memory = 100*(max-available)/max = 100*(192413696- 
      39734096)/192413696 = 79.35%
3. Did another calculation via JMX : java.lang:type=Memory (Using MBean)

   ```
   It gave me following output for the same program.

   Used memory : 127737896

   Max memory : 201850880

   Percentage of used memory = 100*(used/max) = 100* (127737896/201850880)= 
   63.28%
   ```

Could you please help me with the following ?

1. What is the reason for the difference between using JMX and Java Run time APIs ?
2. If I want to know the memory occupied in my JVM heap which is the right approach (point 2 or point 3). My intention is to raise alerts before an out of memory occurs for my JVM.

I have another observation as well. When I use CMS algorithm (with -Xms and -Xms set to 32GB and Occupancy fraction set to 70%) I could see the difference between the free memory calculated using MBeans and java runtime freeMemory(). When I was using G1 I could not find these difference (the Mbeans and run time API gave same value).

Comment: You may find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/790535/2032064) and  [MemoryMXBean documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html) interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will check in detail.

Answer (score 1):

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
long mem = rt.totalMemory();
long fm = rt.freeMemory();
long mm = rt.maxMemory();
long used = mm - fm;
```

Answer (score -2):

The calculation should be *usedMemory / MaxMemory * 100*

```
Used Memory = 127737896
Max Memory = 201850880

127737896 / 201850880 * 100 = 63.28%
```