# Using liveness probe command to restart the cluster if JVM memory usage in a container exceeds 85% threshold

Tags: docker, kubernetes, livenessprobe

I am fairly new to docker, and am trying to devise a short-term fix to provide relief for a cluster container whose JVM is leaking memory. To do this, I am following [this guide](https://spacelift.io/blog/kubernetes-liveness-probe) to add a liveness probe to the .manifest file in the cluster's apiserver.

My plan is for the liveness prob to run an `execAction` command that will look up the container id and determine the relative memory usage of its JVM; if this usage surpasses 85%, then it will fail the liveness prob, which will restart the container and thus reset the memory.

I currently have this outline in my manifest:

```
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - 
      initialDelaySeconds: 
      periodSeconds:
```

I am struggling to find the appropriate command to include that will determine the JVM memory usage in the way I described above and would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Probes are instrumentation to test something within the pod so you have to solve the first part of problem: ***how to determine the [consumed memory by your java processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139909/calculating-used-memory-of-a-jvm)***.

The second part it to create an **executable within the image** (likely a script accepting the percentage threshold as argument) to determine when the threshold is overtaken and exiting with **non-zero code to indicate the pod is unhealthy**.

The probe could be something like:

```yaml
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        - /opt/scripts/liveness.sh
        - 85
      initialDelaySeconds: 20
      periodSeconds: 15
```